# How to change save file location in Divinity: Original Sin?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I have noticed that loading and saving games takes a long time and would like to change the save game location to my rather small SSD. How can I do this?

Clarification: I have a single SSD and have already moved the game files from 'Program Files' to it. My windows installation 'C:*' and 'My Documents' is on the HDD. I would prefer not to move all of 'My Documents' to the SDD.

Answer (score -2):

In order to get the game to load faster, you would need to put the entire game onto the SSD vs just the save file. Loading the game means loading all the assets required to run the game, all of which (I believe its safe to assume) are located on your secondary HDD. The save file should already be on your SSD as the default save location for most games is in your "My Documents" folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the opposite is actually true. I have the game on the SSD (copy+paste from Program Files). 'My Documents' and the rest of the windows installation is on my HDD.

Comment: Ahh haha. I suppose that's what I get for making assumptions :P. I don't have any other suggestions relevant to your situation unfortunately. I feel that the limitation in this case would come from the specs of your computer vs the location of the saved file (there I go making assumptions again). Have you considered installing your OS onto the SSD? I have this and rarely have to deal with loading screens (all of my games are installed on a 7200RPM HDD) even in skyrim and fallout.